# Delta Method in GLM.jl

Tags: julia, glm, marginal-effects

Is hypothesis testing of linear and non-linear functions of coefficients of GLM supported in Julia's GLM.jl?

I am looking for a Julia equivalent of `marginaleffects` package in R which uses the `deltamethod()` function, or the `nlcom` post estimation command in Stata.

Thanks!

Sample R code:

```
eq = lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data)
deltamethod(eq, "x1 / x2 = 1")
```

Sample Stata code:

```
reg y x1 x2
nlcom _b[x1]/_b[x2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Julia Package, 'TargetedLearning' uses the delta method, see:

( https://lendle.github.io/TargetedLearning.jl/user-guide/influencecurves/#the-delta-method )